# How can I prove that $G/M\cap N \cong M/(M\cap N) \times N/(M\cap N)$ where $M,N \triangleleft G$ and $M.N=G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $M\cap N = \{e\}$ then $M/M\cap N = M$, $N/M\cap N = M$ and $G/M\cap N = G$ and $G = M\times N$ trivially by the def of direct product.

If $M\cap N \neq \{e\}$, I was trying to follow the same line of argument , to show that $M\cap N \triangleleft G$ and hence $M\cap N \triangleleft M,N$.

Now, I think $a(M\cap N) \neq b(M\cap N)$ $ \forall a \in M\setminus M\cap N $ and 
$ \forall b \in N\setminus M\cap N $ and therefore
$M/(M\cap N) \cap N/(M\cap N) = \{e\}$

but I am not able to show $(M/M\cap N) \triangleleft (G/M\cap N)$ because this happens
$\iff a(M/M\cap N) = (M/M\cap N)a$ $ \forall a\in G/M\cap N$
$\iff g(M\cap N)m(M\cap N) = m(M\cap N)g(M\cap N)$
$\iff gm(M\cap N) = mg(M\cap N)$
$\iff gm = mg$
which obviously need not be true. Can you please suggest a modification to my approach or a new approach altogether? Appreciate your response.

Comment: In your list of equivalences, what are $m$ and $g$? Also, how do you get from
$$gm(M\cap N) = mg(M\cap N)$$
to $gm=mg$? 
And in your title, should it end with *"...and $MN=G$"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write $K=M\cap N$. In your list of equivalences, you make the step
$$gmK = mgK
\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
gm=mg.$$
Though it is unclear what $g$ and $m$ are, this is not true in general. The implication '$\Leftarrow$' is of course true, but the implication '$\Rightarrow$' is false; it does imply that $gmg^{-1}m^{-1}\in K$, for example.

Because $M,N\triangleleft G$, for all $g\in G$ we have $gMg^{-1}=M$ and $gNg^{-1}=N$. Of course $K\subset M$ and $K\subset N$, so

$$gKg^{-1}\subset M\qquad\text{ and }\qquad gKg^{-1}\subset N,$$
which implies that $gKg^{-1}\subset M\cap N=K$. Because multiplication by $g$ and $g^{-1}$ is bijective, it follows that $gKg^{-1}=K$, so $K\triangleleft G$.

Showing that $M/K\triangleleft G/K$ is now quickly done; now that you know $K\triangleleft G$ the natural map
$$G/K\ \longrightarrow\ G/M,$$
is well-defined. It is surjective because $K\subset M$, so you can use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: True, I did not see that the first equivalence is not true in general. Now, I understand $M\cap N \triangleleft  G$ but I was trying to show $(M/M\cap N )\triangleleft (G/M\cap N)$ which I don't know would be needed to show the final result? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @manifolded I have updated my answer.

Comment: @manifolded I have added a more constructive approach to a proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate that! Let me go through that for a few minutes.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense, thanks for different approaches!

Comment: Hey, just wanted to make the explicit homomorphism $\phi: M\times N \rightarrow G/K$ is $\phi(m,n) = (mn)K$ ?

Comment: $\phi ((m_1,n_1).(m_2,n_2))= \phi ((m_1m_2,n_1n_2)) = m_1m_2n_1n_2(K)$ and $\phi(m_1,n_1).\phi (m_2,n_2) = m_1n_1m_2n_2(K)$.   May I know why they are equal? The elements of M and N commute if $K=\emptyset$, right?

Comment: @manifolded You are right, the two are not equal and the map I suggested is not a group homomorphism. So the first isomorphism theorem does not apply. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that.

Comment: @Servaes The map you suggested is in fact correct. You can check that the commutator $[M,N]$ lies in $K$, which makes the map you appear to have suggested a homomorphism.

Comment: @jgon Thanks, I'll check again. I felt things were getting overly complicated (I thought the approach would be more straightforward), so I let it go altogether.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint/oft encountered approach:** Recall that for a group homomorphism $\varphi : G \to H$ we have

$$G/\ker \varphi \cong \operatorname{Im} \varphi.$$

Pick $G = M \times N$ and $H = M/(M\cap N) \times N/(M\cap N)$ and $\varphi : G \to H$ the "obvious" map (I'll leave it to you to decide whether or not it is obvious).

Comment: I am sorry I don't see why this is a trivial homomorphism? Also, not sure what would be the explicit homomorphism? Thanks.

Comment: Choose $\varphi$ to be the map that sends $(m,n) \in G$ to $(\overline{m}, \overline{n}) \in H$. Can you show that this is a homomorphism? Is it surjective/injective and what is the kernel?

Comment: I can see that this is a homomorphism. As for the kernel, the identity element for H is $(M\cap N, M\cap N)$ and so $(m,n) \in (M\cap N, M\cap N)$ which is $M\cap N$. For surjectiveness, do we say that any element in H is $(m(M\cap N),n(M\cap N))$ and hence $\exists (m,n)$ in $G$?